# How to get the grouped data with true conditions only

Tags: lodash

How to get the grouped data with true conditions only. Below will return both values with key true and false.

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true }
];

 result = _.groupBy(users, { 'user': 'fred' });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [**filter**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter) the data before you group:

```
var result = _(users)
    .filter('active')
    .groupBy('user')
    .value();
```

Comment: I knw this way. If i do it using my code above. It have two list one with false as key and failed list and another with true key with success list.

Comment: Are you trying to find all the objects that have a user called fred? If so then  just use a filter: `_.filter(users, {user: 'fred'})`. Grouping with a matcher iteratee like in your example doesn't really make sense. You would be better off using the lodash function `partition`.